# vloockup in 4 columns, microsoft excel 2013

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hello i need to search within 4 columns in excel with vlookup, but i can't get it to work.
I have tried to google it but i don't know what i should search for?

I have one Sheet that have a list full of information about prices and different art number and i want to be able to search for one art number and see the other.
This is how my code looks like

```
=VLOOKUP(E4;Sheet1!C2:G9999;5;FALSKT)
```

I have tried to divide the `C2:G9999 to C2:C9999+D2:D9999` and so on but it didn't work.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset + match, its more flexible. It lets you search vertically down and horizontally to the right at the same time. I cant say anything more without looking at the actual data. maybe you can provide a dummy dataset?

Comment: I have made one bummy but with the same structure, http://pontaxxr.se/help/Test.xlsx  im using swedish excel so LETARAD = Vlookup and Blad1 = Sheet1

Comment: So, I took a look at the sheet. Heres what I understand. if you enter a art number, it should search all the four columns, find the art number, and then return all the others?